# how do you get out of 'view source' mode in Coda

Tags: coda

I right clicked and selected 'view source' in the Preview window of Coda. It brought up the source code, but I now appear to be stuck there.. I tried going back to Edit and returning to Preview, but no help. Is this a dead end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a toggle right below the left edge of the preview/editor. Two angle brackets:

`<>`

followed by the `!` in a bubble and the standard Search magnifier.